# Unable to load file around 125 GB which includes backslash(\) and values ending with the file delimiter(\|) using COPY command in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a large file around 125 GB with values containing open ended double quotes(") in between the values(56 Link " Road). Also values with backslash() like (Round Table). The file has pipe delimiter. When I use copy command and include ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD=\. The file loads with escaping the open ended double quotes and backslash. Now the issue is that we need to edit the file and replace(\ --> \ and " --> "). This is an additional operation which is taking lot of time and resources.
Is there any other way to load the file ?

Comment: If the file loads as it is, why not fix any data issues in the target table using SQL rather than trying to fix them as part of the load process?

Comment: The file will not load as backslash(\) is used to escape characters in snowflake. So, if it finds \| then it will escape the pipe which is the delimiter for the file. This will result in one column short in the file.